# Getting one, two & three taps working in the same View Controller

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I am using `UITapGestureRecognizer` and is trying to get different taps working on the same ViewController but **fail** with the one-click tap.

I have tried to find a solution but is not able to integrate it to my test code. I would very much appreciate some help with this so i can learn from it.

here is the code i am using to test on:

The .h file:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
```

The .m file:

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer3;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer2;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer1;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {

return YES;

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];


self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

// Create Tap Gesture Recognizer

//==1
self.tapGestureRecognizer1 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handle1Taps:)];
self.tapGestureRecognizer1.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
self.tapGestureRecognizer1.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

//==2
self.tapGestureRecognizer2 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handle2Taps:)];
self.tapGestureRecognizer2.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
self.tapGestureRecognizer3.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;

//== #3
self.tapGestureRecognizer3 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handle3Taps:)];
self.tapGestureRecognizer3.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
self.tapGestureRecognizer3.numberOfTapsRequired = 3;


[self.tapGestureRecognizer1 requireGestureRecognizerToFail:self.tapGestureRecognizer2];
[self.tapGestureRecognizer1 requireGestureRecognizerToFail:self.tapGestureRecognizer3];
[self.tapGestureRecognizer2 requireGestureRecognizerToFail:self.tapGestureRecognizer3];

// Add gestures
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.tapGestureRecognizer1];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.tapGestureRecognizer2];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.tapGestureRecognizer3];

}

- (void)handle1Taps:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)paramSender {
NSLog(@"handle-1-Taps");

NSUInteger touchCounter = 0;

for (touchCounter = 0; touchCounter < paramSender.numberOfTouchesRequired; touchCounter++) {

    CGPoint touchPoint = [paramSender locationOfTouch:touchCounter inView:paramSender.view];

    NSLog(@">>1 x TAP<<");


}

}

- (void)handle2Taps:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)paramSender {
NSLog(@"handle-2-Taps");
NSUInteger touchCounter = 0;

for (touchCounter = 0; touchCounter < paramSender.numberOfTouchesRequired; touchCounter++) {

    CGPoint touchPoint = [paramSender locationOfTouch:touchCounter inView:paramSender.view];

    NSLog(@">>2 x TAP<<");


}

}

- (void)handle3Taps:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)paramSender {
NSLog(@"handle-3-Taps");
NSUInteger touchCounter = 0;

for (touchCounter = 0; touchCounter < paramSender.numberOfTouchesRequired; touchCounter++) {

    CGPoint touchPoint = [paramSender locationOfTouch:touchCounter inView:paramSender.view];

    NSLog(@">>3 x TAP<<");


}

}

@end
```

The following is the result at the first interaction with the VC:

```
 - 1 x tap = >>2 x TAP<<
 - 2 x tap = >>2 x TAP<<
 - 3 x tap = >>3 x TAP<<
```

Comment: I think.... [self.tapGestureRecognizer1 requireGestureRecognizerToFail:self.tapGestureRecognizer2];
[self.tapGestureRecognizer2 requireGestureRecognizerToFail:self.tapGestureRecognizer3];    will be enough... try it

Comment: @Xman thanks but i can still not trigger the single tap!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hey
Check this :
The last line is wrong.**

```
self.tapGestureRecognizer2 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handle2Taps:)];
self.tapGestureRecognizer2.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
self.tapGestureRecognizer3.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
```

**it should be**

```
self.tapGestureRecognizer2.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: This. Because when you don't set `numberOfTapsRequired` of recognizer2  it will consume the single tap that should go to recognizer1

Comment: @Xman that was the problem, thanks. Amazing that i did not see that as I went through the code a lot :-(

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Comment this statement which is present at three places in your code.

```
self.tapGestureRecognizer1.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
```

One more issue, replace

```
self.tapGestureRecognizer3.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
```

to

```
self.tapGestureRecognizer2.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
```

as tapGestureRecognizer2 requires number of taps equal to 2

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is issue with your logic in below bold_highlighted code lines!

> -(void)viewDidLoad { [super viewDidLoad];
>
> self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
>
> // Create Tap Gesture Recognizer
>
> //==1 self.tapGestureRecognizer1 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer
>   alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handle1Taps:)];
>   self.tapGestureRecognizer1.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
>   self.tapGestureRecognizer1.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
>
> //==2 self.tapGestureRecognizer2 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer
>   alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handle2Taps:)];
>   self.tapGestureRecognizer2.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
>   **self.tapGestureRecognizer3.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;**
>
> //== #3 self.tapGestureRecognizer3 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer
>   alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handle3Taps:)];
>   self.tapGestureRecognizer3.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
>   self.tapGestureRecognizer3.numberOfTapsRequired = 3;
>
> **[self.tapGestureRecognizer1 requireGestureRecognizerToFail:self.tapGestureRecognizer2];
>   [self.tapGestureRecognizer1
>   requireGestureRecognizerToFail:self.tapGestureRecognizer3];
>   [self.tapGestureRecognizer2
>   requireGestureRecognizerToFail:self.tapGestureRecognizer3];**
>
> // Add gestures [self.view
>   addGestureRecognizer:self.tapGestureRecognizer1]; [self.view
>   addGestureRecognizer:self.tapGestureRecognizer2]; [self.view
>   addGestureRecognizer:self.tapGestureRecognizer3];
>
> }

Answer (score 0):

To do it programmatically (and with some style).

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress;
int idx;

for (idx = 1; idx <= 3; idx++) {
    longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                           initWithTarget:self action:@selector(buttonLongPressed:)];
    longPress.minimumPressDuration = min_press_duration;
    longPress.numberOfTapsRequired = 0;
    longPress.numberOfTouchesRequired = idx;
    [button addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
    [longPress release];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add `[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];` to handleDoubleTap and handlelTripleTap methods. This will cancel the execution of previous operations.

Comment: this makes no sense. There is not a single perform request (i.e. `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`) in this code

Comment: I realise that my answer was unhelpful, but why is this textual duel on my answer ?? @Matthias, I did not even object to the down vote !
:(